# how to get same value in two components using vuejs $emit

Tags: typescript, vue.js

is that possible when type in **Main** and the value can be at **Test World** too?

**You can check the sample at here** >>> [Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/emittest-t2nqtb?file=/src/components/TestWorld.vue)

What the real problem I am facing is when user add an item to the cart and the cart will add one number above but the i tried to test but must use the component you called to active the $emit. The above sample is most same problem I am facing.

Two components:   Buy = Main, Cart = Test World
[image: buy]

[image: cart]

Comment: @Grant where should i change this.$parent.$emit code?

Comment: @Grant no, please do not suggest such a bad practice as `$parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. It is a two-way binding and is kind of the basis of SPAs. In your parent component, pass the variable as a prop down to the child, then $emit up your variable.

Your component inside your parent.

```
   <NewWorld :yourpropname="this.yourvar" @yourEmitterName="handleEmit($event)" />
```

A method for handling the emit in the parent

```
    handleEmit(data) {
      this.yourvar = data;
    },
```

Inside your child, set a variable = to your prop, then emit that up. The var will be the same in both componenets

You can emit it on any change with something like

```
            @update:model-value="$emit('yourEmitterName', this.yourVar)"
```

Comment: @update:model-value="$emit('yourEmitterName', this.yourVar)" this line of code where should i insert?

Comment: @Meow that one should be on the HTML tag/Vue component, since it's a (Vue) event listener. Check the doc for further details.

Comment: @kissu tried the update:model-value but still no work..

Comment: @Meow what do you see in your Vue devtools? Do you see the event being emitted from the child? Is your parent properly receiving it?

Comment: @kissu https://t2nqtb.csb.app/ i can only see the event name but can't see more details

Comment: @Meow you can see `typed` and click on it to see the actual payload that you're emitting.

Comment: @kissu i can only click the attrs and the ontyped function cannot click... https://ibb.co/fH1BH99

Comment: @Meow it is not supposed to be `attrs`. Check [that one](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#listening-to-events).

Comment: @kissu how can i enable to see event in my vue devtools? https://ibb.co/7kDRw2B

Comment: @Meow go to "Timeline".

Comment: @kissu ok i found it,thanks but the **@update** still no working...  https://codesandbox.io/s/emittest-t2nqtb?file=/src/components/NewWorld.vue